# Logs say "fe_sendauth: no password supplied" but rails console working without problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

I'm trying to deploy rails app with capistrano, nginx and puma. When I visit the app I get errors like this in my production.log:

```
[11c972c9-c8fb-404f-93c3-9fc614ad815b] ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
):
```

When I log to this machine and run `bin/rails console` it works without any problems, I can create records, query records. Connection to database works without problems.

`RAILS_ENV` is set to `production` in `/etc/environment`

Any idea what could be the problem?

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
  username: app
```

pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to delete PostgreSQL completely using,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
```

Click **yes** on that pop-up, re-install PostgreSQL using,

```
sudo apt update
```

then,

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

then,

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Finally, you'll also need to create a database user so that you are able to connect to the database from Rails. First, check what your operating system username is:

```
whoami
```

If your username is "stack", for example, you'd need to create a Postgres user with that same name. To do so, run this command to open the Postgres CLI:
sudo -u postgres -i

From the Postgres CLI, run this command (replacing "stack" with your username):

```
createuser -sr stack
```

Then enter control + d or type logout to exit.